# Power BI - There was an error when processing the data in the dataset

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, pbi.error

I have created a `.pbix` file with 8 reports using Power BI Desktop and published to `app.powerbi.com`. When I tried to refresh the dataset, I am getting below error.

> Data source
> error{"error":{"code":"ModelRefresh_ShortMessage_ProcessingError","pbi.error":{"code":"ModelRefresh_ShortMessage_ProcessingError","parameters":{},"details":[{"code":"Message","detail":{"type":1,"value":"The
> operation has timed out"}}],"exceptionCulprit":1}}} Table:
> report_data_source. Cluster
> URIWABI-AUSTRALIA-EAST-A-PRIMARY-redirect.analysis.windows.net

The value (error occurred table name) of the **Table** `(Table: report_data_source)` is getting changed time to time. There are more than 50 tables used in this report and show the name of one of them as the value for **Table**.

I have checked the API and it's getting the request from Power BI and send the response within 30 secs without issues.

For the reference, query of `report_data_source` as below.

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://bishan.me/api/getPBRData"))
in
    Source
```

And other tables are using `report_data_source` as below,

```
let
    Source = report_data_source,
    annual_report = Source[annual_report],
    #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(annual_report),
    #"Removed Bottom Rows" = Table.RemoveLastN(#"Converted to Table",1),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Bottom Rows",{{"Name", type text}, {"Value", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

When I am refreshing dataset from Power BI Desktop, It's working without any issue. I am getting the dataset refresh issue only in `app.powerbi.com` with `Refresh Now` and `Scheduled Refresh` options.

What could be the issue?